# fail2ban jail not working properly

Tags: nginx, regex, fail2ban

I'm trying to block non-available script requests to nginx with fail2ban.

```
# Noscript filter /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/nginx-noscript.conf:
#
# Block IPs trying to execute scripts such as .php, .pl, .exe and other funny scripts.
#
# Matches e.g.
# 192.168.1.1 - - "GET /something.cgi
#
[Definition]
failregex = ^<HOST> -.*GET.*(\.asp|\.exe|\.pl|\.cgi|\scgi)
ignoreregex =
```

But this also creates a hit if the referrer in the access log holds the script tag.
For instance this line: (I've obfuscated the IP and referer, and I truncated over multiple lines, in the real log these 4lines are on one line.)

```
1.2.3.4 - - [16/Dec/2013:18:01:10 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 
301 178 "http://referrer.com/default.aspx" 
"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.41 Safari/537.36"
```

How can I change the regexp to only find the `.asp` etc in the `GET /xxxxx HTTP` section ?

Comment: Can you please provide a log entry of the type that you are expecting your failregex to match, there needs to be more fixed text to pin down the location of the extensions. For example the apache version of this rule `...script '/\S*(\.php|\.asp|\.exe|\.pl)\S*' not found or unable to stat\s*$`

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is very interesting things in Regular expression, that regular expressions are greedy.

Even if they get the match in the starting of the sentence, they will keep looking and will go for the last match available in the sentence. In your case, it's matching this "referrer.com/default.aspx", because you have regular expression to match for .asp and it will also match anything with .asp*.

So, you need to be very much specific while working with regular expressions.

For this, you should try this:

```
failregex = ^<HOST> -.*GET.*(\.asp|\.exe|\.pl|\.cgi|\scgi)\"\s\d*
```

Something like this should work very well. If by any case it doesn't work, now you know what's the issue, and I am sure you can fix it with a little bit digging in regular expression.

Hope this helped.

Comment: I think we really need to see the king of log entry that the OP is expecting to match their regex against. There really needs to be something that indicates the script was not found to match against too.